# Creating a slow reply from Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to create a Dialogflow webhook that responds to the user slowly, so it more feels like someone is on the other end and takes a few seconds to reply.

I'm using the built-in code editor, and can create an Intent handler (see code), but I just don't know how to get it to reply slower.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function welcome (agent) {
    agent.add(`I'm replying too quickly!`);
  }

  function fallback (agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needing to reply slower is rarely a desired thing, to be honest. But the easiest way to do so is to use `setTimeout()` and delay for a little bit. (Don't delay too long - more than 5 or 10 seconds and Dialogflow will timeout.)

The catch with using `setTimeout()`, however, is that the handler will need to return a Promise. So you'll need to wrap the call to `setTimeout()` and the `agent.add()` in a Promise handler. A function that does this might look something like:

```
function respondSlowly( agent, msg, ms ){
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      agent.add( msg );
      resolve();
    }, ms );
  });
}
```

You would then call this from your handler, providing the agent, the message, and how many milliseconds to wait to reply:

```
function welcome( agent ){
  return respondSlowly( agent, `Hi there, slowly`, 2000 );  // Wait 2 seconds to reply
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle this is to add delay in the UI code.
Keep the Dialogflow Intent as it is, and once the bot response is received on the frontend, show it with a delay.

Below is an example of how we are handling it at [Kommunicate](https://www.kommunicate.io)
Dialogflow response comes without any delay, then on Javascript code, we show a typing indicator animation, add some delay using Javascript before displaying it.

[image: Kommunicate chatbot showing typing indicator for bot reply]